# How to pass a kernel parameter after boot

Tags: boot, nvidia, kernel, 21.10

OS: Ubuntu 21.10, Nvidia driver:470.74

I would like to pass the kernel parameter  "nvidia-drm.modeset=1" after boot (I would like to use nvidia+wayland)
I am not able to do it during boot because of an unusual bug. This parameter conflict with another kernel parameter "intel_iommu=on". If both are on, then my system fails to boot (multiple unrelated boot errors). This issue is only with the 5.13.0 kernel. I do not have this issue with the older 5.8 kernel.

Answer (score 0):

You change the parameters of kernel in /etc/default/grub file.

sudo vi /etc/default/grub

find the line:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="parameters1 parameters2"

sudo update-grub

then you can reboot to see the effect.

Comment: That is the issue. There is a conflict. When the 2 parameters that I need are set. My system does not boot. I can only set one of them during boot the second needs to be after boot.

Comment: After boot, when the system is running, you add kernel parameters through sysctl command.

Comment: When I tried "sudo -w sysctl nvidia-drm.modeset=1" I get the following error: ysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/nvidia-drm/modeset: No such file or directory. Did not work for me.

Comment: Post the result of: sudo sysctl -a | grep nvidia

Comment: " sudo sysctl -a | grep nvidia"  has 0 lines

Comment: then there is no such kernel parameter, share the output lsmod | grep -i nvidia

Comment: nvidia_uvm           1044480  0
nvidia_drm             61440  3
nvidia_modeset       1150976  20 nvidia_drm
nvidia              36904960  997 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
drm_kms_helper        262144  1 nvidia_drm
drm                   561152  7 drm_kms_helper,nvidia,nvidia_drm

Comment: try  find /proc -iname -type d "*nvida", try it in sys also

Comment: No nvidia in /proc. Is this because nvidia is a dkms module